# NX Console : Nx Generate on VSCode on WSL throws an error

Tags: visual-studio-code, wsl-2, nrwl-nx

I have a NX project where I wanted to use the generate script for the nx console.

When clicking on generate I get the following error :

```
 *  Executing task: npx nx generate @nx/angular:component --name=test --project=master-admin --no-interactive 

'\\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu\home\xxxx\xxxx\xxxx'
CMD.EXE a été démarré avec le chemin d’accès comme répertoire en
cours. Les chemins d’accès UNC ne sont pas prise en charge. Utilisation
du répertoire Windows par défaut.
'nx' n’est pas reconnu en tant que commande interne
ou externe, un programme exécutable ou un fichier de commandes.

 *  The terminal process "/bin/bash '-c', 'npx nx generate @nx/angular:component --name=test --project=master-admin --no-interactive'" terminated with exit code: 1. 
 *  Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

As you can see, I'm running VSCode with the WSL client extension.

I don't really understand why is vscode mentionning `CMD.EXE` since I'm on WSL.

Any idea why this is happening ?

FYI, my default terminal is bash.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've opened the folder in VS Code via its local UNC path (\wsl.localhost) instead of opening it through WSL. It's unfortunate that VS Code doesn't warn about this.

You can run `code /path/to/your/project` inside your Ubuntu terminal, or type "WSL" into the VS Code command palette and select one of the "Connect to WSL" options to open the remote folder via WSL instead.

The fastest way to fix this would be if you've already got VS Code running with the local UNC path open, you can just select "WSL: Reopen Folder in WSL" from the command palette.

There are more details in the readme of the WSL VS Code extension here: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-wsl and in the VS Code docs here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/wsl#_open-a-remote-folder-or-workspace

Once you've got VS Code connected correctly your commands should work as expected.

Comment: My project is open in WSL 2 (i've got the little marker in the bottom left) but the nx console is accessing it via the UNC path :(

Comment: Thank you : running "code" inside workspace in Ubuntu did it for me :-)